# Pandas: Filling NA values to be filled based on distribution of existing values

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas data-frame in which one column `sign up` has multiple null values. The `sign up` column has categorical values that includes multiple `OS` such as `iOS`, `android`, `web` etc. 
I would like to fill the `NA` values from the existing `OS` values but the NA values should be filled as per the existing distribution of `OS` values.

Example:
Lets say, the dataset has OS values count distribution as follows:

```
signup
android web    14
ios web        16
mac            5
other          3
windows        6
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

I would like to fill the NA values based on the above distribution of the distinct OS values. The reason that I would like to do is to maintain the current distribution as filling with `Mode` value would likely to skew the results. 
Can someone help on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use something like Numpy's [random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

starting with a frame fitting your description

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

print(df)
    id   signup
0    1      mac
1    2      mac
2    3      mac
3    4    other
4    5    other
5    6  windows
6    7  windows
7    8  windows
8    9  windows
9   10      NaN
10  11      NaN
11  12      NaN
12  13      NaN
13  14      NaN
```

**Updated** using piRSquared's tip in the comments
figuring out the current distribution

```
s = df.signup.value_counts(normalize=True)
print(s)
windows    0.444444
mac        0.333333
other      0.222222
Name: signup, dtype: float64
```

We'll use boolean indexing next to filter by the nans we want to update.  Also, this is where we use the random choice by passing the index (windows, mac, other), the size needed and the distribution of each signup will be used for the probabilities(p) parameter.

```
missing = df['signup'].isnull()
df.loc[missing,'signup'] = np.random.choice(s.index, size=len(df[missing]),p=s.values)
print(df)

    id   signup
0    1      mac
1    2      mac
2    3      mac
3    4    other
4    5    other
5    6  windows
6    7  windows
7    8  windows
8    9  windows
9   10  windows
10  11  windows
11  12  mac
12  13  windows
13  14    other
```

Comment: seems like we didn't understand the problem the same way, his sign up columns is the one with NaN values ?

Comment: Thanks Bob. This was helpful.

Comment: `df.signup.value_counts(normalize=True)`

Comment: Super helpful @Bob

Answer (score 3):

- find nulls
- sample from non-nulls the amount of nulls.  make sure to set `replace=True`
- assign sampled values to null positions

---

```
isnull = df.signup.isnull()
sample = df.signup.dropna().sample(isnull.sum(), replace=True).values
df.loc[isnull, 'signup'] = sample
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I took this as input (because I think in your question you named my `value` column `sign up` by mistake:

```
        signup  value
0  android web   14.0
1      ios web   16.0
2          mac    5.0
3        other    3.0
4      windows    6.0
5      ios web    NaN
6          mac    NaN
7      windows    NaN
```

Knowing that, you problem can be solved in one line as follows:

```
b = df.groupby('signup')['value'].first()[df['signup']]
```

please not that `b` is of type pandas.Series.

but if you want your output to be a DataFrame with the same columns names proceed as follows:

```
b = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('signup')['value'].first()[df['signup']],columns=['value']).reset_index()
b.rename({1:'value'})
```

if you `print(b)`, it outputs:

```
        signup  value
0  android web   14.0
1      ios web   16.0
2          mac    5.0
3        other    3.0
4      windows    6.0
5      ios web   16.0
6          mac    5.0
7      windows    6.0
```